# discordでこのプログラムのどこに何を入れればメッセージを送った人をメンションさせることができますか？

Tags: python, python3, discord

Python3.7を使っています。

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('Hi'):
        await message.channel.send('hello')

client.run("Token")
```

Comment: 参考: 英語版SOでの関連質問と回答 - [how do i mention a user using user's id in discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964328/how-do-i-mention-a-user-using-users-id-in-discord-py)

Comment: @weeuii さん、Python 3.7 をお使いだということは、discord.py のバージョン情報も書いておいた方が安全かと思います。async 周りの修正があるためです。特に、バージョン 1.0 より下なのかどうかで API 周りも変わってきます。

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/176377

Answer (score 2):

`User` クラスの [`mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/api.html#discord.User.mention) を使うと表現できます。以下はサンプルコードです。

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('Hi'):
        msg = f"{message.author.mention} Hello!"
        await message.channel.send(msg)
```

`f" ... "` はフォーマット文字列です。Python 3.7.2、discord.py 1.0.0a1691+gf686924 で動作確認しました。

Comment: @wiiuuxx さん、良かったです :)　もしよろしければ、スタック・オーバーフローでは[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)することができますので、して頂けると私が嬉しいです。