# Discord.pyで天気を表示するボットを作っていたところ以下のようなエラーが出ました

Tags: python, python3, discord

実際のコード

```
import discord
import urllib.request
import json
import re

client = discord.Client()

citycode = '016010'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen('http://weather.livedoor.com/forecast/webservice/json/v1?city=%s'%citycode).read()
resp = json.loads(resp.decode('utf-8'))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("logged in as " + client.user.name)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author != client.user:

    if message.content == "weather":
      msg = resp['location']['city']
      msg += "の天気は、\n"
      for f in resp['forecasts']:
        msg += f['dateLabel'] + "が" + f['telop'] + "\n"
      msg += "です。"

      await message.channel.send(message.channel, message.author.mention + msg)

client.run("token")
```

表示されたエラー

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yoich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 227, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\yoich\OneDrive\Desktop\bot総合\Weathertest.py", line 27, in on_message
    await message.channel.send(message.channel, message.author.mention + msg)
TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

どこをどうすれば正常に起動するのでしょうか？Pythonはpython3を使っています

Comment: `send()` のパラメータが古い版数のものとゴッチャになっているのでは？　ご自身の以前のQ&Aを参考に見直してみてください。[discordでこのプログラムのどこに何を入れればメッセージを送った人をメンションさせることができますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/53023/26370)

Comment: 参考: 英語版での類似質問(と回答) - [TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53560166/2322778)

Comment: 過去質問やマルチポスト先でも度々指摘をされていますが、最低限`discord.py`のバージョンを明記する必要があると思います。

Answer (score 1):

`send()` の部分を次のように変えると動きそうです。

```
await message.channel.send(message.author.mention + msg)
```

`send()` は `message.channel` クラスのメソッドなので、暗黙的な引数として `self` を持っています。したがって元々の呼び出し方だと `self` も含めて 3 引数渡していたことになり、`send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` というエラーが出ています。